# I don't get the e-mail using this code. What is the problem?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

The following is the program, which I am trying to send e-mail. The code is error free and I don't get any run time exception. But the code is unable to send e-mail. I have revised this code a lot but can't get what is actually wrong.
The sender and the receiver both have GMail accounts. The sender has 2-step verification process disabled.  (I don't think it matters for the receiver. Does it?)

The code :

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

class tester {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host" , "smtp.gmail.com");
      props.put("mail.stmp.user" , "username"); // username or complete address ! Have tried both
      Session session  = Session.getDefaultInstance( props , null);
      String to = "me@gmail.com";
      String from = "from@gmail.com";
      String subject = "Testing...";
      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
         try {
           msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
           msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO , new InternetAddress(to));
           msg.setSubject(subject);
           msg.setText("Working fine..!");
           System.out.println("fine!!??");
         }  catch(Exception exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Log the traffic with wireshark, just to learn if the problem is at the sender or at the receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to call [`Transport.send()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send%28javax.mail.Message%29) to send your `MimeMessage`.

Secondly, GMail needs to be configured to use TLS or SSL connection. The following needs to be added to your `Properties` (`props`):

```
//To use TLS
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

//To use SSL
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

---

To connect to GMail SMTP, use the [`Transport.connect()`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Service.html#connect%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. I see you are not using any `Transport` at all in your code, so add this:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport();

//Connect to GMail
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, "USERNAME_HERE", "PASSWORD_HERE");
transport.send(msg);
```

Alternatively, you can create a `Session` by including a `javax.mail.Authenticator` as a parameter.

Example:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("USERNAME_HERE", "PASSWORD_HERE");
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps you.

Resources:

- [Send email with SMTPS (eg. Google GMail) (Javamail)](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0570.html)
- [JavaMail API – Sending email via Gmail SMTP example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Comment: after adding these and adding the statement `props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password")`; i get the following exception **javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?** why do i get this ?

Comment: Specify username and password in transport.connect() call:

Comment: @ maximdim that produces the same exception. I did like this `Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
       transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "username", "password");
       Transport.send(msg);`

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman I get the same exception . EDIT your post to include `"smtp"` in the arguments of getTransport().

Comment: @Suhail Gupta, I don't have to, since (if I configure my properties correctly, I can do [`session.getTransport()`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Session.html#getTransport%28%29).

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman Does it make a difference if i pass `full email address` or just the `username` in the username spot

Comment: @Suhail Gupta, try both ways and see which one works for you.

Comment: Update your post with full source code and exception you're getting.

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610572/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-failed-to-connect-no-password-specifie

Comment: This answer though complete was still incomplete because Authentication was required.The complete answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610572/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-failed-to-connect-no-password-specifie

Comment: @Suhail Gupta, what I wrote was missing pieces to your code and I did include `javax.mail.Authenticator`.

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman The last snippet of your answer , i don't understand it . When is the method `getPasswordAuthentication()` called ?

Comment: It's called by the Session for authentication.

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman but we are sending the password and username using this statement also `transport.send( "smtp.gmail.com " , port ,"username" , "password");` Then why do we require the authentication method ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1255/discussion-between-the-elite-gentleman-and-suhail-gupta)

Answer (score 4):

Well, your code doesn't actually attempt to send the message. Take a look at [`Transport.send`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send%28javax.mail.Message%29).

Here are some examples:

- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=144
- http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/javamail.html

Comment: yes. After `Transport.send()` i get this exception during runtime `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. c5sm1092784p
bh.94`